# doesn't booting after installed updates in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, boot

ubuntu 12.04 LTS doesn't booting after installing the updates .

Recently i have installed ubuntu in my system also i installed latest updates. after installing the updates it doesn't booting and showing the error message as "**could not write bytes: broken pipe**" . what should i do to get into desktop ...

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the iso, but deny any updates. thats what i always do. the iso is a frozen image where most software on the disc works. if one program does not function right look for its upgrade only in repo or on line. try to download its .deb or .rpm or other dot file extension for your distro brand. good luck. I am running Linux Voyager 12.04 LTS and my other laptop runs Linux Lite 12.04 LTS, both are XFCE desktops.  Look at distrowatch.com.